# how to make a laravel function return an array

Tags: laravel

It seems that the previous question was to hard. Let me ask you something simpler.

```
function finduser($id){
DB::table('Books')->where('BooksID',$id)->value('UserID');
Return something
}
```

The Books table has 2 columns: BookId and UserID

i don't know how 'something' should look like, but let's say that 'something' contains 1,2 and 3

in a view i would like to call the function finduser  like this:

```
$data=function(1)
@foreach($data as $d)
{{$d}}
@endforeach
```

Please help me with how 'something' should look like and how to caal it in the view.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you should probably call the function in a controller and then pass it to the view, did you actually try any your code out? Return the whole DB query in function `finduser()`, dump the result, check what you have, go from there.

Comment: I tried this:function finduser(){
    $data=dd(DB::table('Books')->get());
   return $data;
}

in view:
{{finduser()}}

Result is:
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#165 ▼
    +"BookID": 1
    +"UserID": 1
  }
  1 => {#166 ▼
    +"ID": 2
    +"BookID": 1
    +"UserID": 2
  }
]
I'm interested in capturing only the UserID

Comment: This will give you a result with UserID column only to loop through: `$result = DB::table('Books')->select('UserID')->get();`. This will give you an array of user IDs: `$ids = DB::table('Books')->lists('UserID');`. Query builder: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries

Comment: Ok... we are making progress... the $ids part is good for me. The function returns the $ids and in the view i echo with {{dd(..)}} and i get the result: array:2 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 2
]  what i want now is to go through this array with foreach and do something for 1, something for 2... How can i do that please ?

Comment: Well, that is pretty basic PHP. You can find plenty of examples online. As you wrote, you use `foreach` to go through IDs one by one, in the order they were returned. If you need something specific for a certain ID, you use an `if` statement or `switch`. Good luck

Comment: I did   foreach($ids as $id)
        echo $id;  and i'm still getting  array:2 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 2
]

Comment: Does your `$ids` variable hold an array or an *object* with an array? Depending on your Laravel version, you might need to change `lists()` to `lists()->all()`. Try both cases out and google. Google a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function from a view try creating a helper.
Just create a file like this "App\Helpers\MyHelper.php" inside the file something like:

```
<?php namespace App\Helpers;

class MyHelper{
    public static function value($param) {
      return $param;
    }
}
```

Register yout helper in the config\app.php under aliases:
`'CompaniesHelper' => 'App\Helpers\CompaniesHelper'`

After doing this you'll be able to call your helper from a view like this:

```
{{MyHelper::value($param)}}
```